# Unable to load site preferences - Error Message

Tags: error

I have been receiving a error message randomly on a expressionEngine site I created.

You can see teh errror message here http://cl.ly/image/2w1a061e0i0d

Any ideas on what could cause this error? I am running ee v2.5.3

Answer (score 2):

Since this is happening intermittently, I'd guess it's an issue with EE not being able to connect to the database server and not an EE specific issues.

The first place to start would be to contact your web host to see if they are having issues on their end. Record the date/time when you next see this error and have them check the mysql error logs to see if there is a specific error logged at the same time.

You might also take a look at the php error logs to see if anything is logged there that may be related.

Comment: I agree with Anna. That particular error is almost always due to EE not being able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

That could point to a problem with your config.php file. Check that both your config.php and database.php files have 666 permissions.

```
system/expressionengine/config/config.php
system/expressionengine/config/database.php
```

Also check that your details in database.php are all correct as it may be having problems connecting to the database.

If they're both OK then the chances are that there's some problems with the database. At this point in your main index.php file turn on output debugging so we can see any PHP errors being reported by changing:

```
$debug = 0;
```

to:

```
$debug = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. The error happens infrequently so I will need to wait a little bit.

Comment: Just wanted to note NOT to set config and database.php to 777. You do not want these world-writable! The docs say 666.

Comment: Agreed - more here (point 7): http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html#verify-file-permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your database access passcode (server, MySql admin, hosting company interface, etc.), you will need to change the original passcode in the database.php file.